# Interacting between new websocket(A) and new websocket.server(B)

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am newbie to websockets.

I need to build a script in nodejs, which is an interface between two sockets.
wsHTML (act as server) communicates with an html screen and wsORG (act as client) communicates with an server.
When event "open" of wsORG occurs, the script must send a message to wsHTML.
I always get the error wsHTML not defined on command wsHTML.send.

I simplified the problem. I wrote the below code using an open echo server from wersocket.org as wsORG, so it is easy to reproduce the error.

The code I'm using is:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++Script started++++++++++++++++");
// ========================================= Websocket Server for HTML clients ==========================================
const ws_server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 81 });
console.log("+++ws_server instantiated");

ws_server.on('connection', function connection(wsHTML) {
    console.log('\r\nHTML client connected.');
    wsHTML.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('HTML client sent a command: [' + message + ']');
        if(message == "PriceOf411111111111"){
            f_SendMsgToORG(wsORG, "Please, send me the Price of 411111111111");
        }else{
            console.log("Unexpected command received");
        }
    });
    wsHTML.on('close', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('ws_server Closed.');
    });
    wsHTML.on('error', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('ws_server ERROR ' + message );
    });
});

// ========================================= Websocket Cliente wsORG ==========================================
var wsORG = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/');
console.log("+++WebsocketORG instantiated");

    wsORG.addEventListener('open', function () {
        console.log('\r\n\r\nCommunicaton with wsORG estabilished.');
    });
    wsORG.addEventListener('close', function () {
        WebSocketOpenConnection = false;
        console.log('Conection with WSorg was CLOSED');
    });
    wsORG.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        var data = event.data;
        console.log("\r\nWSorg echoed: " + data);
        f_SendMsgToHTML(p_Socket, ("Send answer from wsORG to HTML client: " + data))
    });

function f_SendMsgToHTML(p_Socket, p_message){
    console.log("Send message to HTML client [" + p_message + "]");
    if (typeof(p_Socket) == "undefined"){
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>OPS: Socket undefined>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        console.log(p_message);
    }else{
        console.log("Socket OK");
        p_Socket.send(p_message);
        console.log("Sent to HTML client [" + p_message + "]");
    }
}

function f_SendMsgToORG(p_Socket, p_message){
    if (typeof(p_Socket) == "undefined"){
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>OPS: Socket undefined>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        console.log(p_message);
    }else{
        console.log("Socket OK");
        p_Socket.send(p_message);
        console.log("Sent to ORG [" + p_message + "]");
    }
}
```

When I run the code, wait for WebsocketORG to be initialized and then connect with HTML client, the response is:

```
# node doubt_stackoverflow.js
++++++++++++++++++++++++Script started++++++++++++++++
+++ws_server instantiated
+++WebsocketORG instantiated


Communicaton with wsORG estabilished.

HTML client connected.
HTML client sent a command: [PriceOf411111111111]
Socket OK
Sent to ORG [Please, send me the Price of 411111111111]

WSorg echoed: Please, send me the Price of 411111111111
/usr/local/src/Foxbit/doubt_stackoverflow.js:39
                f_SendMsgToHTML(p_Socket, ("Send answer from wsORG to HTML client: " + data))
                                ^

ReferenceError: **p_Socket is not defined**
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/src/Foxbit/doubt_stackoverflow.js:39:19)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/usr/local/src/Foxbit/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/usr/local/src/Foxbit/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:797:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/usr/local/src/Foxbit/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:437:14)
    at Receiver.getData (/usr/local/src/Foxbit/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:367:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/usr/local/src/Foxbit/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:143:22)
    at Receiver._write (/usr/local/src/Foxbit/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:78:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
#
```

Note thet wsHTML is opened, receives a command, but as I need to answer to it, it gives says that the socket does not exist (probably it was closed, but not by me).

I just have tried a lot but without success.

The doubt is: How I reference wsHTML in wsORG?

Best
carliedu

Answer (score 0):

As I get no ideas how to solve this, I ended up calling for a solution I didn't want.
Now when I receive an ansver from wsORG, I add it to a stack, and timely send the stack to the client. This is processing overhead, but for now, no other solution.